# VRP : Arc cost based on current vehicle load (CO2 Emissions)

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

I would like to factor in the CO2 emission in the Vehicle Routing Problem. The Arc Cost is not the distance anymore but the CO2 emission over each Arc

As a first order approximation, the CO2 emission of each arc can be modeled as a linear function of the current load and constant topographic characteristics of the arc (the slope, distance, altitude, ...)
arc_cost(arc,load) = K(arc) + alpha(arc)*load

K and alpha are functions of the arc only (stateless)
The load depends on the previous deliveries.

I haven't found how to model this with the ORTools Python API. Here is my current attempt : https://github.com/remisoulignac/scm_optim_problems/blob/main/SCM290-GreenVehicleRoutingProblem.ipynb

For now, I fall back on a two-level optimization approach:
A classical VRP optimization model. I parameterize this model by several control points at which I impose a certain weight of goods to be delivered to the chosen route.
A hyperparametric optimization level that will play with the different control points and optimize the overall real fuel consumption of the tour.
Thank you for your help,

Comment: Callbacks must be stateless. So the two level approach, or something like that is mandatory.

Comment: Thanks Laurent. Is it a limitation of the optimization algorithms working behind for the VRP? A limitation of the Python API ?

Comment: A limitation or the algorithm